# Get PHP row index after displaying data on an html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, rowid

I am getting data from a mysql DB using PHP and then displaying it inside a DIV on a web page.
the data Im fetching is a list of task and I want the users to be able to delete a task once completed.

Image here:
http://www.picpaste.com/Tasks-esmvwRPX.jpg 
(apparently I need 10 reputation points before I can embed a picture in my post!)

This is my PHP code used to display the date:

```
<section class="tasks">
        <div id="all-tasks">
            <fieldset class="tasks-list">
                <?php 
                    $strSQL = "SELECT Tasks.bolComplete, Tasks.strTask, Tasks.datDueDate FROM Tasks WHERE Tasks.idPeople ='"  . $_SESSION['UserID'] . "' AND Tasks.bolComplete ='0' ORDER BY Tasks.datDueDate";
                    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
                        echo '<label class="tasks-list-item left">';
                        if ($row['bolComplete'] == 1) {
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="task_1" value="' . $row['bolComplete'] . '" class="tasks-list-cb" checked>';
                        }
                        else {
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="task_1" value="' . $row['bolComplete'] . '" class="tasks-list-cb" unchecked>';
                        }
                        echo '<span class="tasks-list-mark"></span>';
                        echo '<span class="tasks-list-desc">' . $row['strTask'] . '</span>';

                        // Convert Date format 
                        $originalDate = $row['datDueDate'];
                        $newDate = date("d-m-y", strtotime($originalDate));
                        echo '<span class="tasks-list-date">' . $newDate . '</span>';
                        echo '</label>';
                        $i++;
                    }
                ?>
            </fieldset>
        </div>          
    </section>
```

How can I capture the index of the row displayed so I can do my delete query against the task that is selected?

I have a primary key on idTask (not displayed in the task list) which I need to capture for my delete statement.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
M.

Comment: Why don't you use the `id` as the `value` in `echo '<input type="checkbox" name="task_1" value="' . $row['bolComplete'] . '" class="tasks-list-cb" checked>` instead of `$row['bolComplete']`?

Comment: Instead of `name="task_1"`, why not use the `id` of the task instead?

Comment: Set the name of the checkbox to `task[id_here]` and then do a foreach of `$_POST[task]`

Comment: that actually sounds like a really sensible idea! if I get name= idTask... how do I capture it once the user clicks on the row? (sorry, newbie here! learning html, css php and javascript on the fly as Im writing this site to teach myself web dev :)

Comment: Is your user submitting a form or are you using JavaScript?

Comment: to add a task, the user clicks the plus icon in the top right hand corner which opens up an html popup window with a simple form, then Submit uses _Post to write the data to the sql DB, refresh the task list in the originator page and then close the popup window. the code to populate and refresh the task list is the one posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can assign you idTask to your lable i.e.

```
<label id="idTaskXXX" class="tasks-list-item left">
...
<lable>
```

then where ever your code is which is checking for what row is clicked read the id field and use that for deletion

here is an example of how to get id from element: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/arslan007/bLke022v/1/>)

```
<label  id="task1" value="Change" onclick="get_id(this.id)">
Task1
</label>
<label  id="task2" value="Change" onclick="get_id(this.id)">
Task2
</label>
```

javascript to get id:

```
function get_id(id){
  alert('My Id is ' + id);
}
```

Comment: after a bit of tweaking to get it to do what I need it do to, it worked :) thanks a lot everyone and thank you for the code sample too user 1884193 :)